# How to download HLS stream video files and keep in local storage flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I download HLS video files and keep it in local in flutter? I have tried using `dio` package and `flutter_downloader` package but not able to download full HLS video files of Playlist.m3u8.

For example,

URL: https://s3.example/samplevideo/playlist.m3u8

This above is the HLS video file URL it contains `.ts` files so I need to download all the `.ts` files related to `playlist.m3u8` and store it in local.

Answer (score 0):

The .m3u file is a playlist that should contain links of playable media. To download those links, you can use [m3u](https://pub.dev/packages/m3u) plugin to parse the playlist. From there, you should be able to fetch the list of links that you can use to download the files.

Comment: please if you could elaborate on this. I am on a deadline and I badly need to implement the feature to download .m3u8 file from network and store it locally inside app storage and access it later for offline viewing.
The m3u plugin you mentioned reads local file, I guess.

Comment: The m3u plugin does read from File (i.e. local storage). What you can do is download the playlist file, then parse the playlist with the m3u plugin.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Omatt. let me download the file and move ahead from there. will come back to you if needed...

Comment: Did you find an approach on how to download the HSL file? I'm in the same situation